# Move image across screen with variables calculated at runtime

Tags: android, image, animation, translation

I want to make a simple activity that has a ship at one side of the screen and a button. Upon a button being pushed, I want the ship to move X distance upward toward the top. This value X is calculated by values that are defined at run time.

The other stack overflow posts I have read regarding animation and image translations talk a lot about how to move images across the screen using TranslationAnimation objects and other similar classes, but everything I have tried requires literal values or final variables to be given.

I need help getting my image to move across the screen with dynamic variables. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use `Animation`, use `Animator`, it's the new way of doing things.

you can "animate" any attribute of the view (in this case, the `ImageView` the holds your ship). in this case, you can animate the margin to get the effect you want. you want to animate the `layout_marginTop` from some value to 0.

```
View shipView = ...;
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100, 0);
animator.setDuration(1000);
animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) shipView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(0, (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(), 0, 0);
        shipView.setLayoutParams(lp);      
    }
});
animator.start();
```

note this assumes your `shipView` is in a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I tried this for a bit, but still had absolutely no luck. I ended up reaching into the canvas approach. So far it is looking promising.